# How to stop jacocoTestReport from logging when a test is passed?

Tags: logging, github-actions, jacoco

I currently run `jacocoTestReport` as apart of a GitHub Action to generate a test report. At the moment every test that passes has a line logged in the structure of `ClassName > MethodName(MethodArguments) PASSED` where `ClassName` is the name of the test class, `MethodName` is the name of the test method and `MethodArguments` are arguments that the test method takes.

As the project has grown and tests have been added, the output for the GitHub Action is starting to contain a lot of these logs which makes it difficult to find the failing tests when a test doesn't pass.

Is there a way to prevent these log messages being logged and only output messages for tests which fail?

Comment: Without looking at your workflow, you can dump your test results to a file e.g. `tests.out` and after tests are complete you can use some utility to filter failed ones e.g. `grep` on Ubuntu runner. Including your workflow in your question would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem, this is the approach I went with. I'll answer my own question with what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up breaking this down into a few steps:

```yaml
- name: Run Jacoco Test Report
  run: |
    ./gradlew jacocoTestReport --warning-mode=none | grep --color=always -e '^' -e 'FAILED' |& tee ./full_test_report.txt
- name: Failed tests only
  run: |
    grep -vE '(^ *$|PASSED|^> Task|Starting a Gradle Daemon|actionable tasks:)' ./full_test_report.txt
```

I kept the existing "Run Jacoco Test Report" step so that full test output was retained. In this step, I added a `grep` command to highlight failed tests and a `tee` command to output the console output to `./full_test_report.txt`.

Next, I added the "Failed tests only" step which grepped this output file removing a few unwanted regular expressions.